# Rewritting URL by htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

When i click on a link it should redirect to 
for ex; `www.domain.com/demo/item.php?item=abc&id=3`
but in url it should show as `www.domain.com/demo/abc/3`

im Using

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatches
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^demo/(.+) demo/item.php?item=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Please help

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Comment: in getting an error like "internal server error" page not found

Comment: Please share the directory structure you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this one, it will not redirect your URL but if you execute your URL (www.domain.com/demo/abc/3) it will be work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^demo/([0-9a-zA-Z\s_]+)/([0-9]+)(/?)$ demo/item.php?item=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: sorry it didnt work. it displayes the same url on screen. :-)

Comment: you should execute url like (www.domain.com/demo/abc/3) not like (www.domain.com/demo/item.php?item=abc&id=3) That

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this after adding the `rewritebase` directive

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^demo/([0-9a-zA-Z\s_]+)/([0-9]+)(/?)$ demo/item.php?item=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: sorry it didnt work. it displayes the same url on screen. :-)